# Android error saving pictures to sd card

Tags: android, camera, image, sd-card

I have an Android app which is crashing on some phones, and not on others. It has about 5k downloads, and so far has received about 50 crash reports. However, based on the amount of ratings/comments I get from users saying that it's force crashing, I think the percentage of affected users is actually much higher.

As the issue doesn't affect my phone, I've been unable to reproduce the error and debug it as I would like to.

The app takes a picture from the camera, overlays a bitmap on it, and saves the resulting image to the SD card.

Below is my code for the `onPictureTaken` PictureCallback method.

```
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        captureBtn.setVisibility(ImageButton.INVISIBLE); 

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            return;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = null;
        Bitmap finalBitmap = null; 
        byte[] byteArray = null; 
        try {   
            mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options).copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            int width = mutableBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = mutableBitmap.getHeight();
            int newWidth = overlayView.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
            int newHeight = overlayView.getDrawable().getBounds().height();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            matrix.postRotate(90);

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, mutableBitmap.getWidth(), mutableBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            finalBitmap = resizedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap);

            Bitmap overlayBitmap = null;
            if (mWeaponType == wep1) {
                overlayBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wep1);
            } else if (mWeaponType == wep2) {
                overlayBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wep2); 
            }

            if (overlayBitmap != null) {

                matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Bitmap resizedOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlayBitmap, 0, 0, overlayBitmap.getWidth(), overlayBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                canvas.drawBitmap(resizedOverlay, 0, 0, new Paint());
                canvas.scale(50, 0);
                canvas.save();
                //finalBitmap is the image with the overlay on it

                // rotate image to save in landscape mode
                matrix = new Matrix(); 
                matrix.postRotate(270); 
                finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap, 0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                        true);

                // convert final bitmap to byte array
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            }
        }

        catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
            //fail
        }

        try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(byteArray); 
                fos.close();

                // Notify system that SD card has been updated
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                Log.i(TAG, "Picture saved, intent broadcast that SD has been updated");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

        finally {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            captureBtn.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

I get a NullPointerException as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:256)
at com.mypackage.MyActivity.onPictureTaken(MyActivity.java:215)
```

which is the

```
 fos.write(byteArray);
```

line.

The `getOutputMediaFile` method listed above is as follows:

```
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("HalfLife2 Booth", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

I think that the problem may be in here somewhere, in trying to get an output media file. I've tried updating the app to use:

```
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
```

instead, and one user has reported the issue to be fixed, but several have reported that it persists.

Any ideas, anyone? I'm finding this a tricky one to debug/fix when I can't reproduce or get anywhere near it.

Comment: make sure you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> in manifest

Comment: I think the issue would occur on all phones if the permission was not set.

Comment: That's correct, the permission has been set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are scaling your pictures in their raw format.  I found that the raw images are HUGE on some phone models.  I recommend scaling the image if it's very large because you will run your virtual machine out of memory.

Example:

```
     imageRef = sd_card_path+"/"+ImageName;
                BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                resample.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageRef, resample);
                int width = resample.outWidth;
                int height = resample.outHeight;
                if(width*height > utility.IMAGE_SIZE_MIN){
                    int imageSizef = (int)(width*height/utility.IMAGE_SIZE_MIN);
                    String imageSize = imageSizef+"";
                    resample.inSampleSize = Integer.parseInt(imageSize);
                    resample.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageRef , resample));                    
                }else{
                    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageRef ));
                }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion! How would I go about achieving that?

Comment: I realize the example uses a file in so here is a line straight from camera stream:

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0 , image.length, resample);

Comment: Thanks Android Addict, can I ask you what your "utility" object is, and where the value for your "IMAGE_SIZE_MIN" comes from?

Comment: The Utility class is just a singlton I use to hold data needed in various parts of the app, ie like the image size.  I generally scale if the image is larger than 800x600 so the min value in that respect is simply the product of that calculation or a total of 480000 pixels.  A phone with an 8 megapixel camera will create a raw image that is 8 million pixels, you see where I am going with this?  I am not certain, but I understand the memory consumption to be 3 times resolution for each (red, green, blue) pixel reference. Hope that helps.  :^)

Comment: BTW, the virtual machine max memory allocation is 16Mb.  So, in the 8 megapixel case, you would certainly exceed the vm budget!  The ONLY way to get around that budget is to build native apps using the NDK.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful! I've implemented that, hopefully it fixes the issue for others. I'll have to release an update and see!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept as answer to help others know it resolves the issue.  thanks :^)

Answer (score 1):

Given the Exception trace it would suggest that you are hitting an OutOfMemorryError and as such the byteArray is never getting populated so you are passing null to the fos.write method

Comment: This is correct, there is a fuller explanation of the issue in the accepted answer. Thank you for your help.